# QSortFilterProxyModel: inconsistent changes reported by source model

Tags: qt, qt4, qabstractitemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

So I have a QTreeView widget that has a custom QSortFilterProxyModel as a source model, which itself wraps a custom QAbstractItemModel called: `sourceModel`.

My tree displays files and folders. If a file removal leaves a folder empty, the folder is automatically deleted. The implementation is below:

```
bool sourceModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent)
{
    if (parent.isValid())
    {
        auto parent_node = static_cast<Node*>(parent.internalPointer());
        if (!parent.data(rootNode).toBool())
        {
            beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                parent_node->removeChild(row + i);
            endRemoveRows();

            if (parent_node->isType<Folder>() && parent_node->children() == 0)
            {
                removeRows(parent_node->row(), 1, parent.parent());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when removeRows is called via the proxy model, but in another instance when sourceModel calls removeRows directly, I get:

> QSortFilterProxyModel: inconsistent changes reported by source model

It's as if the QSortFilterProxyModel isn't receiving or handling beginRemoveRows/endRemoveRows properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this, the fix had nothing to do with the models themselves and the code posted works fine. I was calling a method directly from a context menu workflow and this was causing some sort of race condition between the proxy model and a selection model.

Comment: Bit late, but I had this issue in past. It was due to the fact that my model was running in different thread to proxy. You have to ensure that all model/proxies/etc run in main thread of qt. `model->moveToThread(qApp->thread());`